# How to run groovy/geb tests in JMeter?

Tags: groovy, jmeter, phantomjs, spock, geb

How would I go about running geb tests in JMeter?

I have compiled a jar of my test and have created a BSF sampler in JMeter. I have installed the groovy plugin for Jmeter.

My test class looks something like this:

```
class LoginLogoutTest extends GebSpec {
  def "Login Logout"() {
    given: "Go to the Login Page"
    LoginPage loginPage = to LoginPage

    when:
    loginPage.login("admin", "password")
    then:
    DashboardPage dashboardPage = at DashboardPage

    when:
    dashboardPage.logout()
    then:
    waitFor {at LoginPage}
  }
}
```

I've used Gradle to build the jar with all the required dependencies for this test class.

Then in my JMeter BSF sampler I have set the language to groovy and written the following script. My web-test.jar is in JMeters \lib directory as some tutorials have shown.

```
import com.geb.tests.LoginLogoutTest;

LoginLogoutTest myTest = new LoginLogoutTest();

myTest."Login Logout"(); //if commented out i get no errors
```

When I try to call the `"Login Logout"()` function JMeter throws the follolwing exception:

```
WARN  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.BSFSampler: BSF error org.apache.bsf.BSFException: exception from Groovy: groovy.lang.MissingFieldException: No such field: $spock_sharedField__browser for class: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject
```

If I don't call the method Jmeter does not throw any errors so I'm assuming I am initializing the class from my jar correctly in my JMeter script.

The reason for doing this is so we can perform load testing by running multiple threads of this test using PhantomJs.

Comment: Why would you run Geb tests from jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Groovy Out of the box in JMeter through JSR223 Samplers:

- Before JMeter 3.0 , download Groovy, copy embeddable/groovy-all.jar to jmeter/lib and restart JMeter
- Starting from JMeter 3.0, Groovy is embedded

Comment: So don't use BSF, try JSR223 instead. What is the "groovy plugin" you write about ?

Comment: I'll give it a shot. The plugin is basically what you described. simply importing all the groovy jars into jmeter/lib/ext. I think the issue is that I'm attempting to call the spock test as a function. Perhaps this is not possible?

Comment: No luck with JSR223 :( getting the same exception. Makes me suspect I'm calling the spock test incorrectly

Comment: I found a spock sampler on github that solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a Spock sampler for JMeter that works. I'm able to run my tests.
Here's the link if anyone else is interested. [JMeter Spock Sampler](https://github.com/gabehamilton/jmeter-spock-sampler)
However, when running single threaded tests, just to see that the sampler works, the chrome browser stays open. Not quite sure why. This would be an issue when running multiple thread because there would be many browsers left open. The goal is to use a headless browser, phantomjs, which I've also gotten to work. But if I run multiple threads with the headless browser there are multiple instances left behind and visible in the windows task manage process list lol.